# How to crop out a specific object

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to get a cropped image from a virtual controller that is shown on a screen in FIFA with OpenCV but it just doesn't crop it out fully.

With the code I have now I get the following outputs:

Output:

Cont Output:
[image: Cont Output]

Crop Output:
[image: Crop Output]

But I need the output to be like this:

Right Output:
[image: Right Output]

Controller:
[image: Controller]

Comment: Did you not already ask this question once before a few days ago?

Comment: Do you have to locate the controller or is it always in the same location on the screen. If the latter, there is no need to do anything but crop the same x,y,w,h every time. Just measure it manually and use that set of values.

Comment: I'm stupid, I just now understood what u said, for some reason I was fixated on the rectangle part but I can just use that again when I have the x,y coordinates. I got it thanks @fmw42